# What does assigning something like {0x7fc00000} to a union mean?

Tags: c++, c++03

I am porting some code from Visual studio to mingw. After resolving some issues I cam across the following issue. I am getting the error

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'DataU::DataU(const char [1])'
 static const DataU NAN  = {0x7fc00000};
                    ^
```

This is the code that I am using

```
static const DataU NAN  = {0x7fc00000};
```

and this is the data structure

```
union DataU {
    uint32_t u;
    float f;
};
```

I do not have much experience with unions however I got the basics from [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++Structures.html)

I am still confused as to why I am getting an error on this statment in GCC.

```
 static const DataU NAN  = {0x7fc00000};
```

From what I understand the copy constructor of DataU should be called. However that union does not have a custom copy constructor.
This is C++03 and I dont understand why the `{}` are used here. Any suggestion on how I could resolve this issue would be appreciated.

**Update:**
I am really not sure where I am getting this error from. However I hope this output assists the question

```
: error: no matching function for call to 'kt_flash::DataU::DataU(const char [1])'
 static const DataU NAN  = {0x7fc00000};
                    ^
C:\Users\admin\kflash.cpp:55:20: note: candidates are:
C:\Users\admin\kflash.cpp:11:7: note: kt_flash::DataU::DataU()
 union DataU {
       ^
C:\Users\admin\kflash.cpp:11:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
C:\Users\admin\kflash.cpp:11:7: note: constexpr kt_flash::DataU::DataU(const kt_flash::DataU&)
C:\Users\admin\kflash.cpp:11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char [1]' to 'const kt_flash::DataU&'
C:\Users\admin\kflash.cpp:11:7: note: constexpr kt_flash::DataU::DataU(kt_flash::DataU&&)
C:\Users\admin\kflash.cpp:11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char [1]' to 'kt_flash::DataU&&'
C:\Users\admin\kflash.cpp:55:25: error: expected ',' or ';' before '=' token
 static const DataU NAN  = {0x7fc00000};
                         ^
In file included from C:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/d3dx9math.h:26:0,
                 from C:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/d3dx9.h:31,
                 from C:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/d3dx9math.h:21,
                 from ./ktafx.h:36,
                 from <command-line>:0:
C:\Users\admin\kflash.cpp:59:25: error: no match for call to '(const kt_flash::DataU) (const char [1])'
 const float FLOAT_NAN = NAN.f;
                         ^
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 7 second(s))
3 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 7 second(s))
```

Comment: This code [does not give that error](http://gcc.godbolt.org/). Please post the actual code that gives the error.

Comment: Is there a chance that `NAN` is a macro defined in the implementation that produces the error?

Comment: @AnT `#include <cmath>` on gotbolt's gcc actually does `#define NAN` so you are onto something

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Dont know why I still get a downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is syntactically and semantically fine at the first sight. However, `NAN` is a standard C macro defined in `math.h`. This is the reason it triggers weird errors. You are not supposed to use this name in your code.

The code compiles fine by GCC if `NAN` is replaced by some other name. But once you call it `NAN` and include `cmath` (or `math.h`), it triggers errors. In my experiment the error message is different though.

Change the name from `NAN` to something else.

Comment: will changing the name of the variable from `NAN` to something else assist ?

Comment: On the implementation I have (mingw 4.9.2) we have `#define NAN __builtin_nan("")` . In fact N3936 Table 119 explicitly says that `NAN` is a reserved identifier for `<cmath>`

Answer (score 3):

That's an initializer, not an assignment.

In an initializer like:

```
static const DataU NAN  = {0x7fc00000};
```

the value `0x7fc00000` initializes the *first* declared member of the union -- in this case, `u`.

This is specified in section 8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr] paragraph 16 of the [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) draft of the C++ standard:

> When a union is initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer, the
>   braces shall only contain an *initializer-clause* for the first
>   non-static data member of the union.

I expect the same wording is in other editions of the standard (and similar wording in the C standard as well).

But I think the cause of the error message is your use of the identifier `NAN`. That's a macro defined in `<cmath>` or `<math.h>`; it expands to an expression representing a floating-point NaN (Not a Number). Changing the identifier will likely fix the problem. (And I see that [AnT's answer'(https://stackoverflow.com/a/29357570/827263) mentioned this before I did.)